# Testbench: having trouble monitoring register outputs of inner modules

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I've been studying Verilog for a short while, and I'm having trouble testing a module I created (it's a 4-bit counter).
Here's my code:

```
module Counter4bit(input clk,rst,load, input[3:0] parallel_input,
 output reg[3:0] o);

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if(rst) begin
            o <= 4'b0000;
        end
        else if(load)   o <= parallel_input;
        else begin
            o <= o + 4'b0001;
        end
    end

endmodule

module CT4TB;

    reg[3:0] Pinp = 4'b0000;
    wire[3:0] out = 4'b0000;
    reg rst=0;
    reg ld=0;
    reg clk=0;

    Counter4bit ct(clk,rst,ld,Pinp,out);

    initial begin
        #15 rst = 1;
        #15 rst = 0;
        $monitor("%t |clk = %d |output = %d",$time,clk,out);

        repeat(35) #50 clk = ~clk;

    end

endmodule
```

When I simulate this, I get X on "out" for all values except 0. It's shown in the picture below.

[image]

The interesting part is, if I move the "$monitor" part into the inner module, I'll get the values I want. The modified code will be like this:

```
module Counter4bit(input clk,rst,load, input[3:0] parallel_input,
 output reg[3:0] o);

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if(rst) begin
            o <= 4'b0000;
        end
        else if(load)   o <= parallel_input;
        else begin
            o <= o + 4'b0001;
        end
        $monitor("%t |clk = %d |output = %d",$time,clk,o);
    end

endmodule

module CT4TB;

    reg[3:0] Pinp = 4'b0000;
    wire[3:0] out = 4'b0000;
    reg rst=0;
    reg ld=0;
    reg clk=0;

    Counter4bit ct(clk,rst,ld,Pinp,out);

    initial begin
        #15 rst = 1;
        #15 rst = 0;
        

        repeat(35) #50 clk = ~clk;

    end

endmodule
```

But, if I add a wave to the outer module for "out", it will be X again.

Please tell me where the problem is.

First code:

```
module Counter4bit(input clk,rst,load, input[3:0] parallel_input,
 output reg[3:0] o);

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if(rst) begin
            o <= 4'b0000;
        end
        else if(load)   o <= parallel_input;
        else begin
            o <= o + 4'b0001;
        end
    end

endmodule

module CT4TB;

    reg[3:0] Pinp = 4'b0000;
    wire[3:0] out = 4'b0000;
    reg rst=0;
    reg ld=0;
    reg clk=0;

    Counter4bit ct(clk,rst,ld,Pinp,out);

    initial begin
        #15 rst = 1;
        #15 rst = 0;
        $monitor("%t |clk = %d |output = %d",$time,clk,out);

        repeat(35) #50 clk = ~clk;

    end

endmodule
```

Result:

[image]

Second code:

```
module Counter4bit(input clk,rst,load, input[3:0] parallel_input,
 output reg[3:0] o);

    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
        if(rst) begin
            o <= 4'b0000;
        end
        else if(load)   o <= parallel_input;
        else begin
            o <= o + 4'b0001;
        end
        $monitor("%t |clk = %d |output = %d",$time,clk,o);
    end

endmodule

module CT4TB;

    reg[3:0] Pinp = 4'b0000;
    wire[3:0] out = 4'b0000;
    reg rst=0;
    reg ld=0;
    reg clk=0;

    Counter4bit ct(clk,rst,ld,Pinp,out);

    initial begin
        #15 rst = 1;
        #15 rst = 0;
        

        repeat(35) #50 clk = ~clk;

    end

endmodule
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues.

Your "output" always shows as X or 0 because you have contention in the testbench module.  The `out` signal has multiple drivers:

1. The `wire` declaration continuously assigns it to 0.
2. The module instance connection continuously drives it with the instance output port `o`.

When `o` is 0, it matches the `wire` value (0).  This is why you see output=0.  When `o` is any value other than 0 (like 1, 2, etc.), there is contention, and you see output=X.

To fix the contention, change:

```
wire[3:0] out = 4'b0000;
```

to:

```
wire[3:0] out;
```

Using `$monitor` is not the best tool for the job.  It changes on every clock edge, which is usually not very meaningful.  I recommend deleting the `$monitor` line, and adding this code into the testbench:

```
always @(negedge clk) begin
    $display("%t |output = %d", $time, out);
end
```

I removed the `clk` signal from the display.  This code will display the `out` signal once per clock cycle.  I chose `negedge` to avoid race conditions.

Output:

```
         130 |output =  1
         230 |output =  2
         330 |output =  3
         430 |output =  4
         530 |output =  5
         630 |output =  6
         730 |output =  7
         830 |output =  8
         930 |output =  9
        1030 |output = 10
        1130 |output = 11
        1230 |output = 12
        1330 |output = 13
        1430 |output = 14
        1530 |output = 15
        1630 |output =  0
        1730 |output =  1
```

Here is the full testbench code:

```
module CT4TB;
    reg[3:0] Pinp = 4'b0000;
    wire[3:0] out;
    reg rst=0;
    reg ld=0;
    reg clk=0;

    Counter4bit ct(clk,rst,ld,Pinp,out);

    always @(negedge clk) begin
        $display("%t |output = %d", $time, out);
    end

    initial begin
        #15 rst = 1;
        #15 rst = 0;
        repeat(35) #50 clk = ~clk;
    end
endmodule
```

---

While the `$monitor` in your `always` block does what you want, it is not a good practice.  You should only call `$monitor` once, in an `initial` block when you do use it.